# Flex AdvancedDataGrid Drag Drop select item on hover

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Flex AdvancedDataGrid, While dragging the item,i wanted to select the item beneath the dragging item.
Same like when we open explorer of windows and try to move a file while moving the directories beneath the moving file gets selected.

Comment: I am looking for the exact same thing, only Flex 3.5.  Two advanced data grids, I want to drag an item from one to the other, doing a replace on which ever row it lands on.  Right now, I am only able to do it by having the user select the row they want to replace in the target grid.  I am curious if you found anything in your search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [3rd party tool](http://www.flexicious.com/Home/Ultimate) overcomes all the drawbacks that you  find in `Flex` data grids.

Go through the demo and get the trial version. It save lots of coding efforts. I faced the same issue but then i used this data grid and solved lots of problems.

Comment: If you have no relation with the '3rd party tool', please state it in your answer. People can think you answer is a promotional one.

Comment: We are the developers of the "third party tool" in question. The answer author is more than likely a customer. We do not have an employee by that name.